# pivottable display html in table

Tags: javascript, html, pivot-table, pivottable.js

I am trying to use https://github.com/nicolaskruchten/pivottable, basically I want to show image in the table. What I've done so far is ; but it wont display the image as img tag instead it considers it as string

```
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $("#output").pivotUI(
        [ 
            {product: "product1", image: "<img src='image1' alt='' height='42' width='42'>"}, 
            {product: "product2", image: "<img src='image2' alt='' height='42' width='42'>"}
        ]
    );
});
</script>

<p><a href="http://nicolas.kruchten.com/pivottable/examples/index.html">« back to examples</a></p>
<div id="output" style="margin: 10px;"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: This is now a supported feature :)

Comment: I had to unfortunately remove support for this feature after all as it created an XSS security vulnerability. See https://github.com/nicolaskruchten/pivottable/pull/401 for details

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the table renderer does not support html values for th elements, it sets explicitely the `textContent` property of th you must create your own renderer.
You have two choices:

1.Create a renderer based on Table renderer code and change `textContent` to `innerHTML`. I will use a jsfiddle snippet since the render function is pretty big: http://jsfiddle.net/u3pwa0tx/

2.Reuse existing Table renderer which displays the html as plain text but before returning it to the parent to be appended, move all th text to th html.

**Edit**: I created a pull request on main repository https://github.com/nicolaskruchten/pivottable/pull/214

```
$(function(){
    var rendererHtml = function(){
        var result = pivotTableRenderer2.apply(this,arguments);
        $(result).find('th').each(function(index,elem){
            var $elem = $(elem);
            $elem.html($elem.text());
        })
        return result;
    }

    $("#output").pivotUI(
        [ 
            {product: "product1", image: "<img src='image1' alt='' height='42' width='42'>"}, 
            {product: "product2", image: "<img src='image2' alt='' height='42' width='42'>"}
        ],{
            renderers:{
                'table2Renderer': rendererHtml
            }
        }
    );
 });
```

Comment: I salute you friend it works perfect except when I drag n drop image field onto pvtAxisContainer pvtHorizList. I doesnt display image there

Comment: @Ktt in which version it does not work? first or second? It were multiple `textContent` properties and I updated all on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/u3pwa0tx/1/

Comment: It was first one and I checked it now and it works! thank you very much

Comment: I also updated my answer that I sent a pull request with this feature on the main repository and if the maintainer accepts it you will be able to use it directly from pivot.js

Comment: I also created an issue yesterday, https://github.com/nicolaskruchten/pivottable/issues/213 maybe you can also answer it there to contribute as well

Comment: There is a point in your script. you say like       th.innerHTML = txt; //<===================edited here. what do you mean by that?

Comment: there is a little incident too, please check http://jsfiddle.net/u3pwa0tx/2/. it is bug when you set columns and rows when initializing

Comment: you should pass renderers along with rows and cols: http://jsfiddle.net/n7pngdhg/1/