# Display links in pivottablejs cells

Tags: javascript, html, pivottable.js

I am currently trying to display links in the pivottablejs cells. I reused the function from this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26002789/pivottable-display-html-in-table). [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/4ckp870b/) is a working snippet without using `hrefs` in the `a` tag.

```
<div id="output" style="display: none;">,id,link
0,1,<a>Google</a>
0,2,<a>Google link</a>
</div>
```

But when I add double quotes or single quotes to be able to generate a real link:

```
<div id="output" style="display: none;">,id,link
0,1,<a href="www.google.com">Google</a>
0,2,<a href="www.google.com">Google link</a>
</div>
```

the `$.csv.toArrays` function complains with a `Uncaught Error: CSVDataError: Illegal Quote` error. How can I avoid the quote error? I am currently stuck and not sure how to resolve this issue. I am a beginner in javascript.
Thanks for any pointers and suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what the problem was. Before passing the table string into `$.csv.toArrays` function I needed to get rid of the double quotes from the table:

```html
<div id="output" style="display: none;">,id,link
0,1,<a href=https://www.google.com>Google</a>
0,2,<a href=https://www.google.com>Google link</a>
</div>
```

and then replace the double quotes with single quotes like this:

```js
$.csv.toArrays($("#output").html().replace(/"/g, "'"))
```

and then it worked and displayed the text as a hyperlink to the correct location.